# How to call a API url by passing localStorage value as a parameter in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

In my application I am trying to call an API by passing localStorage value as a parameter .

product component:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.productCode = this.CartdataService.selectedProduct;

     this.myItem = localStorage.getItem('Item_Code');
     console.log("1st :" + this.myItem);

    if(this.myItem !=this.productCode){  
      this.myItem = this.CartdataService.selectedProduct;
      console.log("2nd :" + this.myItem);
    }

    this.CartdataService.get_Product_Details(this.myItem).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("3rd :" + this.myItem);
        console.log(data);
        let key = 'Item_Code';  
        localStorage.setItem(key,this.myItem); //setting localStorage value
      });
  }
```

Here what I am trying to do is when the product component is get called first check for the product code in service (which is passed another component to service).if it's available then I need to check it with the localStorage value ,If it is different then call the url with the service data if it is same then call the url with localStorage data.

Every time the last used product code is stored in the localStorage.

I have tried something like in the above code but it's not worked .
Can anyone help me to solve this .

Comment: You should assign data to `localStorage.setItem(key, data)` instead of `this.myItem.`

Comment: can you share this.myItem response data?

Answer (score 0):

```
//set your **localstorage** data using **JSON.stringify**

       var data=[{'test':'data'}];

      localStorage.setItem('Item_Code',JSON.stringify(data));

//than get localstorage like below using **JSON.parse**

 var localdata=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Item_Code'));
```

Answer (score -1):

I could not see where did you set 'Item_Code'.

For the first time it would be undefined only. Is there any other function which is setting the localStorage prior to this ngInit.

Also you didnot change this.myItem, at anywhere inside the subscribe also. I mean it is not the one got from the response.

```
this.CartdataService.get_Product_Details(this.myItem).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("3rd :" + this.myItem);
        console.log(data);
        let key = 'Item_Code';  
        localStorage.setItem(key,this.myItem); //setting localStorage value
      });
```

In this you are simply logging the this.myItem but not assigning something like,

```
this.myItem = data.myItem;
```

Kindly clarify!

Comment: please check the code one again it's already there @PadmapriyaVishnuvardhan

Comment: Please check my answer as well, and hope you understand what I am trying to say here

Comment: inside the if condition assigning the value to myItem .

Comment: EIther you need to change the this.CartdataService.selectedProduct or this.myItem as per the "data" or something. Otherwise it would be same for ever. From your code snippet here, I could not see when your this.CartdataService.selectedProduct will change.

Comment: this.CartdataService.selectedProduct it will get changed when the user select another product from the appComponent.If the user not selected any products but load the product component  I need to show the data with the previously selected product code

Comment: I could understand the problem now. It is because of the object You need to copy the object instead of direct assignment. Try like this in your if condition this.myItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.CartdataService.selectedProduct));